# Searching a key word in a pdm file and pulling that key word

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

So I have code that will search through the directories to find files that have cdm at the end of he file name. I save the pathways of the files into a data frame. How can I add to my search a way to find the word "ID" in these files and then pull the 16 digit random number that is right beside this word? Just to add this ID is in the file. I would also want to store these ids in the dataframe. The reason I want to automate it is because there are 457 files.

This is an example of the formating:

```
<?PowerDesigner AppLocale="UTF16" ID="{F4847BC0-D005-4204-964A-9C0DFE28416E}" Label="" LastModificationDate="1609351245" Name="WORKPLACE INVESTING BACKUP" Objects="857" Symbols="302" Type="{1E597170-9350-11D1-AB3C-0020AF71E433}" signature="CDM_DATA_MODEL_XML" version="16.7.1.6488"?>
```

The value that I want is the value after ID.

```
import os  
import pandas as pd
#This variable was created to save time by staring it at the W folder and go from there.
current_dur = r'Workplace'
#empty data frame to put the file paths in.
cdm_files = []


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dur):
    for file in files:
         if file.endswith('.cdm'):
            pdm_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

cdm_filesdataframe = pd.DataFrame(cdm_files)
cdm_filesdataframe.rename(columns = { 0 :'Directory Path'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the content of a cdm file?

Comment: I can not, but I can tell you a cdm file is a conceptual data model in PowerDesigner software.

Comment: You search the word 'ID' inside the file or in the path or in the filename?

Comment: I want to search for the word ID in the file and pull the ID into a dataframe.

Comment: So fake the content of a cdm file and edit your post else nobody will be able to help you. Just few lines where we can see 'ID' and its value.

Comment: This is an example of the formating. <?PowerDesigner AppLocale="UTF16" ID="{F4847BC0-D005-4204-964A-9C0DFE28416E}" Label="" LastModificationDate="1609351245" Name="WORKPLACE INVESTING BACKUP" Objects="857" Symbols="302" Type="{1E597170-9350-11D1-AB3C-0020AF71E433}" signature="CDM_DATA_MODEL_XML" version="16.7.1.6488"?> The value that I want is the value after ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find `ID` attribute in each `.cdm` file (or the `lxml` package what should be better). I also replaced `os.walk` by `pathlib.glob`. Here the code:

```py
import re
import pathlib

root_dir = pathlib.Path(r'\\the\path')

data = []
for cdmfile in root_dir.glob('**/*.cdm'):
    with open('powerdesigner.cdm') as cdm:
        # skip first line: <?xml ...?>
        next(cdm)

        # Read next line: <?PowerDesigner ...?>
        # if sre := re.search(r'ID="\{(?P<ID>[^\{]+)\}"', cdm.readline()):
        sre = re.search(r'ID="\{(?P<ID>[^\{]+)\}"', cdm.readline())
        if sre:
            data.append((sre.group('ID'), cdmfile))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'FilePath'])
```

Comment: I ran the code. Maybe I did it wrong but I am getting a syntax error at sre := after the if statement.

Comment: @StevenMarsh. It's because your python version is < 3.8. I fixed my code.